# Oracle/APEX Adding a row to an Interactive Grid with a Dynamic Action

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Currently using APEX 5.1.4

My goal is to have the user press a button, which triggers a new row to be added to the bottom of the IG. This row would also need to have some default values pre-populated, such as the sequence column I have functioning as a primary key.

Doesn't matter how exactly, but I was considering doing it with Javascript. However, none of the methods I have found online, regarding adding a row with Javascript, work.

Also, I have the header bar of the IG removed, so finding the native Add Row Button probably is not an option.

--EDIT--

I found some Javascript that successfully allows me to add a row, however, it adds the row directly underneath the currently selected row. I do not see any methods to automatically select the last row of the IG, and it still doesn't solve that the row needs to have some dynamic values upon instantiation.

Here is the javascript:

This shows all of the available functions that can be invoked ( with .invoke() ):

```
apex.region("id-region-emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").list()
```

These following lines both instantiate a new empty row on the IG:

("row-add-row" adds to top of IG, "insert-record" adds underneath currently selected row.)

```
apex.region("id-region-emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("row-add-row")

apex.region("id-region-emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("insert-record")
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use below code:

```
apex.region("detaildataset").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("selection-add-row");
```

Answer (score 0):

Before applying this code make `interactiveGrid` editable by clicking on attributes and also apply primary key on one column and then apply this code in Execute javascript code:

```
apex
  .region("detaildataset")
  .widget()
  .interactiveGrid("getActions")
  .invoke("selection-add-row");
```